# Disable/Block a Key with another Key while its pressed and held down

Tags: autohotkey, game-development

So in this game im moving my charachter with the **WASD** keys, but if i hold down the **A** and **D** key at the same time,
the game register that as a forward movement (**W** key **|**) so the charachter starts to move forward instead of the strafe actions (Left) \  (right) **/**.

So i need a code which is prevents the **A** and **D** key simultaneous pressing.

[CHECK THIS GIF, SO U CAN SEE WHAT I MEAN!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GugpF.gif)

I want **A** and **D** override each other (Im not using the **W** key), because if i hit both **A** and **D** at the same time my character moves forward, not like this **\  /**
and i want to avoid the forward movements.

I want insantly changed fast Left \ and Right **/** strafing only.

Here is the code what i got so far:

```
~a::
If (GetKeyState("d", "p"))
{
    Send {d up}
    d = 0
}
Return

~d::
If (GetKeyState("a", "p"))
{
    Send {a up}
    a = 0
}
Return

a up::
If (d)
{
    Send {d down}
    d = 0
}
Return

d up::
If (a)
{
    Send {a down}
    a = 0
}
Return
```

*Basicly this code almost working.*

The problem is if i don't change the numbers i can't change directions continuously i need to let go the keys. It stops after 1 direction change. If i change the numbers its working, but after a few direction change its getting toggled either left or right. Even if i let it go its moving left or right....

Any ideas? thx

Answer (score 2):

This should work. Try it and let me know.

```
$*a::
$*d::
    SendInput, {a Up}{d Up}
    StringReplace, hk, A_ThisHotkey, % "$*"
    SendInput, {%hk% Down}
    KeyWait, % hk
    Send, {a Up}{d Up}
return
```

Comment: hey GroggyOtter 

sry for the late reply. script is working, but only once. its for a game im playing. if im holding down the a key and start to hold down the d key as well script is working as it should it release the a key. but after i let go the d key i have to hit the a key again. im usually always holding down one of the 2 keys. now i have to release them and thats an issue. do you know any workaround?

thx

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: You can play around with the code below. Maybe it will help you out

```
#SingleInstance, force
#Persistent
#NoEnv
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey, 1

~a & d::
~d & a::
Send, {a up}
key := "d"
SetTimer, pressdown, 10
return

~d::key := "d"
~a::key := "a"
~a up::key := "d"
~d up::key := "a"

pressdown:
if GetKeyState(key, "p")
{
    SendInput, {%key% down}
    SetTimer, pressdown, 30
}
else {
    SetTimer, pressdown, Off
    SendInput, {%key% up}
}
return
```

This script cannot allow A, or D to be simultaneously pressed.

Comment: Code looks good and simple but its not working. U can test in a text editor. check the gif what i provided for the code. the script what i found is working better than urs and i dont know why but it is :D any idea? thx tho